# Pair strings based on unique substrings

Tags: java, string-matching

I have two sets of strings that I need to match, if possible, by identical substrings in each pair (bold text in examples below; bold/capitalization only done here for emphasis there's not a way to identify the key substring by looking at a list element on its own) that are unique within each list.  The remaining portion (lorem ipsum) of the text may be common to many elements or may be completely unique.

List one:

1. "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, **CANDY BAR** consectetur adipisicing
   elit,"
2. "sed do eiusmod **CANDY CANE** tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
   magna"
3. "sed do eiusmod tempor **HOMER** incididunt ut labore et dolore
   magna"
4. "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing **PICKUP
   TRUCK** elit,"
5. "ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute"

List two:

1. "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt **HOMER** ut labore et dolore magna"
2. "aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, **CANDY BAR** quis nostrud exercitation"
3. "aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud **CANDY CANE** exercitation"
4. "irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore"
5. "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing **PICKUP TRUCK** elit,"

From the sample text below matches are: 1-2; 2-3; 3-1; 4-5

element 5 in list one and element 4 in list 2 don't match with anything.

Comment: How can we extract the substring, i mean do we know that each unique substrings are uppercase or what?

Comment: Why is "tempor" not marked as 2-1 solution? Do you have a more mathematical definition of the question?

Comment: @mgaert tempor isn't unique.  It's in both lines 2 and 3 of list 1.

Comment: @deporter I only bold/upper-cased the strings to make them more obvious in my example text.  There's nothing special about the text in the real data.

Comment: @mgaert Unfortunately not.  I'm not sure how to set the problem up at all.  Via visual inspection doing it isn't bad; but the data isn't consistent enough in structure from one set of lists to the next to make writing a small number of special cases feasible.  If there isn't a general solution available, the matchup step is going to have to be done manually.  It's not a disaster if this happens since there are steps that require much more complex/extensive understanding of free form text fields; but I'm trying to automate as much of the process as possible.

Comment: A quick look would make me think that a loop over each string in the first list and using `.contains()` with each substring would do what you want.

Comment: @Jon bruteforce is a potential option but would be O(nasty); and might end up being too slow depending on how big the worst case ends up being.  I was hoping there was a reasonably commonish algorithm that performed significantly better than the naive brute force option, and which was available in a library I could link to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the total amount of data you are dealing with is relatively small, the solutions already suggested (using `.contains()` or regular expressions) are probably most practical. **The below is a way of doing it when the amount of data is much larger.**

The key part of the solution is to use **suffix arrays.** A suffix array is a lexicographically sorted list of all suffixes (in the sense of string ends, not linguistic suffixes) of a text (or a concatenation of multiple texts).

In the example you've described, this would involve constructing a suffix array of the concatenated texts of **one of the two sets** only. I'll assume we do this for **set 2**, so we would concatenate all sentences, using a unique separation character (I have chosen the hash character `#` below):

```
 sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt HOMER ut labore et dolore magna#aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, CANDY BAR quis nostrud exercitation#aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud CANDY CANE exercitation#....
```

Next, you'd construct the **suffix array of that string**, along with the **longest-common prefix array (LCP).** Both data structures can be constructed using a brute force approach if the amount of text is not extremely large. Alternatively, there are libraries for building them more efficiently, for example [jSuffixArrays](http://labs.carrotsearch.com/jsuffixarrays.html).

Finally you iterate through the sentences of **set 1**, and in each sentence through the candidate starting positions of relevant tokens (probably only words that follow white space or punctuation) and search the suffix array of set 2 for them. **Searching a suffix array** when the LCP array is available can be done in O(n+m) time (n is the length of the concatenated string of set 2, m is the length of the candidate string you are looking for) using the [classical search algorithm by Manber and Myers](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=6527002138193581338&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5), but if that is still too slow, there are refined methods available, e.g. described by [Navarro and Mäkinen 2007](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=9064982197003274356&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5).

For each match you find, the suffix array can readily provide with information on how frequent the string occurs in set 2, and in how many different sentences. I can elaborate on how to do the latter in an edit to this post if needed.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting multiple methods depending on how large the worst case is.  I'm still trying to scope it myself.  The biggest I've seen so far is probably within the same order of magnitude as the dummy data I posted (more, but shorter strings).  Unfortunately I don't know if the worst case I've seen so far is comparable to the worst case we'll have to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you have a list of strings that are unique within each list.  These strings are then part (substrings) of the Strings in the lists.  I would create a list of such substrings and then compare them using regex (rather no java substring as in this case you would need to know start index).

Comment: actually I don't know what the unique substrings are; nor is there a guarantee that they'll exist.  In most cases they should; but when dealing with human entered free form data there are no guarantees.